# Should I use load or require in IRB?

Tags: ruby, irb

I had the impression that I should use `require 'some_path'` to get a file or a library I want to use, but I couldn't get it to work, and `load 'some_path'` worked.

When are the different times when I should use these?

Also, is it possible to import a directory with the `load` or `require` commmands? I am trying to use a whole directory, but so far I could only get one file at a time with `load`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Dir to list all the files ending with .rb and require/load them

```
 Dir["/path/to/dir/*.rb"].each { |file| load_your_file_here(file) }
```

I recommend requiring file and then including the module that file loads... If you are not using module or class inside your file than maybe you should reconsider your structure.

load might have some unintended consequences and it's not performant.

Answer (score 1):

Once you call require for a file further calls of require will no longer require it again(i.e. will have no effect), while load will reload it every time you call it. As far as I know there is no way to load a whole directory.